# True/False questions in Moodle package (LaTex)

Tags: exam

I am using Moodle Package (fom CTAN) to make quizzes for Moodle. All is going well except I cannot find question type True/False in the manual or google.

It does have question types multi (Multiple Choices), shortanswer (Short Answer), numerical (Numerical fill in the blank), cloze(Mix of three above) and matching.

Any help or idea to tweak available question types (to add True/False) would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the following an option: a multiple choice with 2 possibilities "True" and "False"

Comment: It will not display the words "True" and "False" (or T / F ) as options.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem (especially with the 'True' / 'False' part). Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: expanding on @albert's comment: looking at the package documentation aren't you simply supposed to `\begin{multi}{Q1}Einstein was born in 1879.\item* True \item False\end{multi}`? (untested)

Comment: Please put your reply as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @albert can you convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to display the words "True" and "False" in as type `multi` with these 2 options. A small example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{moodle}
\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{My first quiz}
\begin{multi}[points=3]{A first test}
Is $8+3 = 11$?
\item* True
\item False
\end{multi}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is a good solution. However, note that a True/False question on Moodle will automatically translate the two options offered depending on the user's language settings.